# "gz-cmake3", but CMake did not find one. Error during building ros_gz_template_project

Tags: gazebo, ros-humble

Does anyone has the same issues with CMAKE could not find "gz-cmake3" during colcon build ros_gz_template_project?

I have try to search for answer (https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/issues/11) by changing the find-package name but still error.

**Environment**

- OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04
- Gazebo Version: Fortress
- Device: NVIDIA Jetson Orin Nano DevKit (Jetpack 6.0)

**Step to Produce**

1. Clone the repo (https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template)
2. Run colcon build

**Output**

[image: Output Terminal]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! You need to install `gz-cmake3`. Does `sudo apt install libgz-cmake3-dev` help?

Comment: unfortunately there is no libgz-cmake3-dev yet, the latest is libgz-cmake2-dev after doing sudo apt update

Comment: You can install it from source: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-cmake?tab=readme-ov-file#building-from-source

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
find_package(ignition-cmake2 REQUIRED)
```

The library name use ignition and not ign or gz.
I raised the error in the [issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/issues/11) page, the yaml is wrong about the version name.

But do notice, on the branch of 'fortress' the [CMakeLists](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template/blob/fortress/ros_gz_example_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt) and all plugin calls are updated correctly

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and add the link to the issue?

Comment: Hi @Eyal, thanks for the feedback. I believe it is correct, I have changed related name to ignition and the error gradually disappear but as it reached the end part (BasicSystem.hh and FullSystem.hh), another error arise. Did you have the same issue?